# Convert System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String

Tags: string, azure, powershell

I am trying to create a script that shows the IP set in the firewall of a Azure SQL server, for that I am using the following code:

```
$sqlservers = Get-AzSqlServer 

foreach ($server in $sqlservers)
{

 $sqlserver = $sqlservers.ServerName
 $sqlRg = $sqlservers.ResourceGroupName
 $firewallIP = Get-AzSqlServerFirewallRule -ServerName $sqlserver -ResourceGroupName $sqlRg
  
}
```

But I am getting this error

```
Get-AzSqlServerFirewallRule : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'ServerName'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:11 char:56
+ ... rewallIP = Get-AzSqlServerFirewallRule -ServerName $sqlserver -Resour ...
+                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-AzSqlServerFirewallRule], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.FirewallRule.Cmdlet.GetAzureSqlServerFirewallRule



Get-AzSqlServerFirewallRule : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'ServerName'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:11 char:56
+ ... rewallIP = Get-AzSqlServerFirewallRule -ServerName $sqlserver -Resour ...
+                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-AzSqlServerFirewallRule], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.FirewallRule.Cmdlet.GetAzureSqlServerFirewallRule
```

Home somebody can help me

thanks in advance

Comment: You're currently passing _all the servers_ and _all the resource groups_ at once. `$sqlserver = $sqlservers.ServerName` -> `$sqlserver = $server.ServerName`, and the same for `$sqlRg`

Comment: i have tried the way you just wrote but still get the same error:

$sqlservers = Get-AzSqlServer 

foreach ($server in $sqlservers)
{

 $sqlserver = $sqlserver.ServerName
 $sqlRg = $sqlserver.ResourceGroupName
 $firewallIP = Get-AzSqlServerFirewallRule -ServerName $sqlserver -ResourceGroupName $sqlRg
  
}

Comment: You declare `$server` as the loop variable in the `foreach()` statement, so _use `$server` inside the loop_, not anything else

Comment: this >>> `$sqlserver = $sqlservers.ServerName` <<< will put ALL the server names into the $Var on the left. the same problem happens in the next line. DO NOT DO THAT. [*grin*] instead use >>> `$sqlserver = $server.ServerName` <<< to get the _current server name_ from the _current server object_.

Answer (score 0):

You used the array ($sqlservers) of servers to assign $sqlserver and $sqlRg you need to change it to the $server

```
$sqlservers = Get-AzSqlServer 

foreach ($server in $sqlservers)
{

 $sqlserver = $server.ServerName
 $sqlRg = $server.ResourceGroupName
 $firewallIP = Get-AzSqlServerFirewallRule -ServerName $sqlserver -ResourceGroupName $sqlRg
  
}
```

Comment: Thank you all, i followed your suggestions and now my script works